# MigLayout - panel with grow and push

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I am trying to create a panel, using MigLayout, divided on three rows. The first and last row should have a pushY of some ratio (in this case, 2f) and the row in between should grow as mush as possible in order to occupy the remaining space.

However, I have some cases in which the last row, for example, which is a panel on its own, will have no components in it. In this case, I want the 2nd row to occupy all the height and I can't achieve that.

Please not that making it invisible is not possible due to other flow-dependencies.

I've attached the code here:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createPanel(true);
    createPanel(false);
}

private static void createPanel(boolean removeAll) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill().gridGap("0", "0").insetsAll("0")));

    panel.add(new JLabel("first row"), new CC().grow().newline().pushY(2f));

    JTextArea abc = new JTextArea("abc");
    abc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
    panel.add(abc, new CC().push().grow().newline());

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill().gridGap("0", "0").insetsAll("0")));
    pnl.add(new JLabel("aaa"), new CC());
    pnl.add(new JLabel("bbb"), new CC().newline());
    pnl.add(new JLabel("ccc"), new CC().newline());
    panel.add(pnl, new CC().grow().newline().pushY(2f));
    if (removeAll) {
        pnl.removeAll();
    }
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(100,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `dock` feature for that, so top will dock in north, bottom in south, and middle row will grow between them. http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf check the page no.5 for docking tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I need all three rows to grow, but with a certain proportion. If I just dock the top to north, and bottom to south and still keep the pushY, it won't help me, since the top and bottom rows won't increase their size.